# Power BI (Dax) Measure variance between same subcategory item, but different country

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having an issue creating a measure. I keep getting 100-0 instead of 100-75

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujno0.jpg)

Comment: Please share the measure(s) you have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing the Dax for _Canada to below one for this case:

```
Var _Canada = Calculate([Cost], Filter(All(table_name), table_name[Country] = "Canada"), Filters(table_name[subcategory]), Filters(table_name[PartNumber]))
```

You will have to do the same for _US if you want to see the result WRT Canada as Country

Comment: I already tried that variant and the basic result is that it uses the total for the Canada Category subtracts it from the US subcategory total. I.e. If the total Canada category = $500, it calculates as $100 - $400.

Comment: Please check the updated dax with **FILTERS** condition added to group data for sub category and partnumber columns. If you can share the same dataset it will be good for me to try these dax on it and get the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer made me go back in and test things. Come to find out the issue was: the dimension table that was connected to the fact table for country. In the fact table I had a country_ID which joined to the country dimension table. I made the post simple, but instead of "Canada", I had Canada's associated ID in the measure and the same for US. I guess it can't be done this way. The simple solution was to just change the fact table column to be the country name and it works fine now.

Comment: Good to know it helped in finding the solution.